# Add Typing to an object wrapper

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add typing to a class that wrap objects and arrays. I was able to do it easily for objects.

```
interface IObject1  {
    value1: string,
}

interface IObject2 {
    myObject: IObject1,
    myObjects: IObject1[]
}

interface Wrapper<T>{
    $<K extends keyof T>(
    selection: K
  ): Wrapper<T[K]>;
}

const wrappedObject2: Wrapper<IObject2> = undefined as any;

//This correctly get the type Wrapper<IObject1>
const wrappedObject1 = wrappedObject2.$('myObject');
```

But keyof doesn't works with array indexes so the following is not working:

`const wrappedObject1InsideArray = wrappedObject2.$('myObjects').$(1);`

I was able to have it working with the following code, but I'm afraid I might be abusing typescript:

```
interface IObject1  {
    value1: string,
}

interface IObject2 {
    myObject: IObject1,
    myObjects: IObject1[]
}

type ValuesOf<T extends any[]> = T[number];

interface Wrapper<T extends any, U extends any[]= any[]>{
    $(selection: number): Wrapper<ValuesOf<U>, ValuesOf<U>>;
    $<K extends keyof T>(
    selection: K
  ): Wrapper<T[K], T[K]>;
}

const wrappedObject2: Wrapper<IObject2> = undefined as any;
const wrappedObject1 = wrappedObject2.$('myObject');
const wrappedObject1InsideArray = wrappedObject2.$('myObjects').$(1);
```

What I don't like with this solution is that wrappedObject1 and wrappedObject1InsideArray have the type `Wrapper<IObject1, IObject1>`. Something that shouldn't happen since IObject1 is not compatible with `T extends any[]`

So I was wondering if there is a better solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems [it's difficult to get `keyof T[]` to include `number`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13715).  In lieu of that, how about this:

```
interface Wrapper<T> {
  $<K extends keyof T>(
    selection: K
  ): Wrapper<T[K]>;
  $<A>(this: Wrapper<A[]>, selection: number): Wrapper<A>
  __brand?: T
}
```

I added a second overload of `$`.  This function has [a `this` parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6018) of `Wrapper<A[]>` for some `A`, which means you can only call it on an object which is an *array* wrapper.

Well, actually, the compiler had a hard time telling the difference structurally between, say, `Wrapper<IObject1>` and `Wrapper<IObject1[]>`.  I guess it's because the only difference was in the generic part of the signature of `$`.  So to fix that I added an optional phantom `__brand` property of type `T`, which allows the compiler to definitively tell the difference between a `Wrapper<T>` and a `Wrapper<U>` if `T` and `U` are different.  This property doesn't need to exist at runtime, and only needs to be there to help the compiler.

Okay, let's use it:

```
const wrappedObject2: Wrapper<IObject2> = undefined as any;
const wrappedObject1 = wrappedObject2.$('myObject');
const expectedError = wrappedObject2.$('myObject').$(0); // IObject1 is not an array
const wrappedObject1InsideArray = wrappedObject2.$('myObjects').$(1);
```

Everything works as you expect, and note how you are prevented from calling the second overload in `expectedError`, since the `this` parameter is inapplicable.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.